# Sinatra steam helper doesn't work

Tags: websocket, sinatra

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Counter < Sinatra::Base
    set :server, 'thin' # 'webrick' doesn't work either
    get '/' do
        haml :index
    end


    get '/stream' do |out|
        out << 'first sentence'
            sleep 0.5
            out << 'second sentence'
            sleep 0.5

    end
    run!
end
```

I follow the guide in the README file, which suggests Thin server works. But it gives me a empty page whereas webrick serve the page with the two sentences altogether without the stream  effect.

Could someone let me know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [Sinatra:  The blog](http://www.sinatrarb.com/blog)

```
get '/stream' do
  stream do |out|
    out << "It's gonna be legen -\n"
    sleep 0.5
    out << " (wait for it) \n"
    sleep 1
    out << "- dary!\n"
  end
end
```

notice line: 2 `stream do |out|`